# link overlaps with the paragraph in responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to move link so it doesn't overlaps with the paragraph. I was trying to apply top and margin-top but link just won't move. Also below the link I have a hr line. I was trying to lower it down as well but it stays still. Not sure how to fix that. Please see the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<p class="teaser">There are lots of discussions happening around the future of EU citizens living in the UK, whether they will or will not be able to stay in 
the island. Another question is how it is going to affect Brittish citizens living in the EU and another question is what is going to happen with
 British citizens travelling to Europe. Would you as a UK citizen will be required to apply for visa to fly over to Spain or any other destination in 
 Europe?There are lots of discussions happening around the future of EU citizens li</p>
<figure>
 <a class="back" href="articles.html">Back to articles</a>
</figure>

<hr class="bottom-line">
```

**CSS (desktop) :**

```
.teaser {
    text-align:justify;
    margin:auto;
    width: 50%;
    line-height:1.5;
    position:relative;
    top: 20px;
    text-align:justify;
    text-indent:2%;
    line-height: 2;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.back {
    text-align:center;
    top:5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
    font-size:25px;
    color: black;
}
.back:hover {
    color: #2347b2;
}
.bottom-line {
    text-align:center;
    width:50%
}
```

**CSS (responsive) :**

```
.teaser {
    width: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    top:45px;
}   
.figure back {
    margin: auto;
}
.bottom-line {
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Max Visna, you have a lot of answers to this question.  Have we solved your problem?  You should award someone the points.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you forgot to pad the bottom.

Just add the following code to the .teaser:

```
padding-bottom: 30px;
```

That should fix the problem for you.

Oh and also your .figure is wrong, change that to this:

```
figure .back { insert code here }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by `position:relative;` assigned to `.teaser`. You can remove it to fix this.

You should consider reading about the [**`position`-Property**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) to get a deeper understanding.

Although you got some duplicate attributes in your CSS file, for example `text-align` and `line-height`. You could check these using a `css linter`.

Answer (score 1):

So...a few things wrong here.  `<figure>` is an element not a class so would not begin with "."  You also repeat it in your "responsive" css file.  Not sure how you think that's supposed to work but you need media queries to differentiate between the two.

You also need to remove `position:relative`, which is what's causing your problem.

Comment: Hi Dave, yes I use media query for a responsive design.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thank you your answer was helpful. Do you mind explaining why exactly position:relative was causing the problem?

Comment: Because "relative" means "relative to its normal position."  Not "relative to the position of others" or even "relative to the <div> in which it lives."  If you make something relative nothing else moves relative to it, hence why the rest of the text was crashing in.  Agreed with Marian below, there are a lot of great sites that explain this.  The one that set me straight was http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: But how the link was relative to the teaser if they are independent elements?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position:relative` from `.teaser`

```css
.teaser {
     text-align:justify;
     margin:auto;
     width: 50%;
     line-height:1.5;
     top: 20px;
     text-align:justify;
     text-indent:2%;
     line-height: 2;
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
     font-size: 20px;
    }
    .back {
     text-align:center;
     top:5px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
     font-size:25px;
     color: black;
    }
    .back:hover {
     color: #2347b2;
    }
    .bottom-line {
     text-align:center;
     width:50%
    }
    .teaser {
        width: 100%;
     margin:auto;
     top:45px;
    } 
    .figure .back {
     margin: auto;
    }
    .bottom-line {
     width:100%;
     margin:auto;
    }
```

```html
<p class="teaser">There are lots of discussions happening around the future of EU citizens living in the UK, whether they will or will not be able to stay in 
</p>
    <figure>
         <a class="back" href="articles.html">Back to articles</a>
    </figure>
<hr class="bottom-line">
```